# Problema con la visualización del main_activity.xml

Tags: android-layout

Como podéis ver por las imágenes, me sale sólo un pixel (arriba a la izquierda) cuando agrego elementos de paleta, en lugar de las constrains que aparecen en la segunda imagen. Cuando paso el puntero por encima salen las flechitas de desplazamientos pero no tienen ninguna influencia aparente.

[image: Me sale sólo un pixel (arriba a la izquierda) cuando añado elementos de la paleta]

[image: Se supone que me debía salir esto]

Estoy trabajando con Oreo y siguiendo el manual del propio Android Studio

Estos son los errores que me aparecen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

**AMPLIACIÓN**
Parecería que no has incluido la Biblioteca de compatibilidad V7 o algún componente más específico en el Gradle. – A. Cedano

He ido al enlace ofrecido y me comenta que mire esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo esto (que por cierto, no se parece en casi nada a lo de la respuesta, me ha costado un poco encontrarlo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que sí está instalado lo que comenta esa respuesta, ¿no? Lo deseleccioné y lo volví a seleccionar para que se reinstalara y no ha cambiado nada.

También he seguido el paso de agregar la dependencia y me ha pasado esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me olvidó comentar que todo esto sucedió nada mas instalar el Android Studio, en la primera aproximación al manual. Cuando me pasó esto, porque otra vez lo instalé todo en otro ordenador y no pasó esto, lo desinstalé todo y lo volví a instalar, por si había ido algo mal y no cambió.

Con esto también quiero decir que necesito una respuesta for dummies, porque, aunque llevo programando muchos años, soy bastante profano en Android Studio.

Gracias otra vez!

**AMPLIACION 2**

Borrado, limpiado TODO, recién instalado, creo nuevo proyecto y me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hablas de un layout pero porque no lo agregas  a tu pregunta? . Revisar [ask].

Comment: Parecería que no has incluido la [Biblioteca de compatibilidad V7](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features?hl=es-419) o algún componente más específico en el Gradle.

Comment: Perdonad por la etiqueta, pero era la más cercana que encontré entre las que podían ser. Disculpad si ha resultado confuso, pero me obligaba a poner una.

Answer (score 0):

Qué pasada... ésta era la solución al problema:

[Enlace origen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863790/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-appcom)

> This can be solved by changing AppTheme in res -> values -> Styles.xml
>   change your theme from
>
> ```
> style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
> ```

Me parece un poco pasada que venga mal de base el Android Studio, supongo que porque he querido hacerlo en Oreo y no está bien implementado para ello aún.